# Override method for a family of subclasses

Tags: c++, overriding

Given legacy code, the system has the following hierarchy of classes:

```
          Base
          ^
          |
----------+---------------
^      ^     ^     ^     ^ 
|      |     |     |     |
A1     B1    C1    D1    E1
^      ^     ^     ^     ^ 
|      |     |     |     |
A2     B2    C2    D2    E2
.......
^      ^     ^     ^     ^ 
|      |     |     |     |
An     Bn    Cn    Dn    En
```

The hierarchy represents messages in some specific domain.

*Base* class is of course base class of all messages.  A1..E1 are messages belonging to version 1 of the domain, A2..E2 to version 2, and so on.  Please note that An must inherit directly from An-1, since An overrides specific methods of An-1.

There's some functionality that is common to all messages, so it's defined as *Base::PerformFunctionality*. Some part of the functionality is specific to version *n* only, so there's virtual function *Base::SpecificPartOfFunctionality*, which is called by *Base::PerformFunctionality*.

So my problem is how to override *Base::SpecificPartOfFunctionality* by all An..En.

I see 2 possible solutions, which I don't like too much:

1. Implement *Base::SpecificPartOfFunctionality* in each and each An..En.

   The problem with this solution is that the implementation should be **exactly same** for each class, so I just repeat the code.

   Additional problem is that if a new class Fn is introduced, developer may forget to implement *SpecificPartOfFunctionality*.
2. Introduce *BaseN* class deriving from Base, while each An..En derive from *BaseN* too:

   ```
   class BaseN : public Base {
      //...
      SpecificPartOfFunctionality() { ...}
   };

   class An: public An-1, public BaseN { .. }
   ```

   The problem with this solution is that it introduces *diamond* problem.

   Additional problem is what will happen if some other version *m* needs to override *Base::SpecificPartOfFunctionality* too. Following the solution we'll introduce *BaseM*, which will override *Base::SpecificPartOfFunctionality*. So which  *SpecificPartOfFunctionality* will be called for *An* - of *BaseN* or of *BaseN*. It's complete mess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the classes A1..E1? If so, why not implement `SpecificBase` which implements `SpecificPartsOfFunctionality` from which A1..E1 derive, in a single inheritance scheme.
`SpecificBase` derives from `Base`, of course.

Comment: I'm allowed to change A1...E1. I think you're describing solution 2 proposed by me.

Comment: not exactly, since you are using multiple inheritance (hm... your syntax seems incorrect.)

Comment: @Constantinius thanks, fixed. An must inherit directly from An-1. I can not insert SpoecificN between them.

Comment: Yes I understand. But if you change the roots, namely A1..E1 to inherit from `SpecificBase` all descendends also have `SpecificBase` in their inheritance hierarchy. So no multiple inheritance is necessary.

Comment: @dimba, "An must inherit directly from An-1" could you explain why and edit it into the question, so that people don't have to waist their time providing you with that particular answer?

Comment: @dimba, well, no problem, but you somehow dropped the word "directly". So is my answer correct or not?

Comment: @avakar - thanks, fixed. I was examining your solution, but you've deleted it..

Comment: @dimba, yes, I forgot to derive my mixin from `Base`; Fred Nurk provided the correct answer.

Comment: @avakar - hovewer you was 1st one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Base {
  virtual void PerformFunctionality() {
    stuff();
    SpecificPartOfFunctionality();
    more_stuff();
  }
private:
  virtual void SpecificPartOfFunctionality() {}
};

template<class Prev>
struct Version3 : Prev {
protected:  // Not private if v4's override might need to call this.
  virtual void SpecificPartOfFunctionality() {
    v3_specific_stuff();
  }
};

struct A1 : Base {};
struct A2 : A1 {};
struct A3 : Version3<A2> {};

struct B1 : Base {};
struct B2 : B1 {};
struct B3 : Version3<B2> {};
```

The only downside is you can't easily forward constructors in current C++, and are probably going to always use the default constructor for A2 and B2 just for simplicity.

In C++0x, however, you can forward constructors:

```
template<class Prev>
struct Version3 : Prev {
  using Prev::Prev;
  //...
};

struct C2 : C1 {
  C2(int);  // No default constructor.
};
struct C3 : Version3<C2> {
  C3() : Version3<C2>(42) {}
};
```

---

> Please note that An must inherit directly from An-1, since An overrides specific methods of An-1.

You have misunderstood something.  An does not need to inherit *directly* from An-1.  For example, this works just fine:

```
struct Example {
  virtual void f();
};

template<class B>
struct Intermediate : B {};

struct Concrete : Intermediate<Example> {
  virtual void f();  // Overrides Example::f.
};
```

Remember that if this *didn't* work, then your An couldn't override SpecificPartOfFunctionality from your Base class in the first place!  An doesn't directly inherit from Base in any of your examples.

Comment: The fact that An should derive directly from An-1 doesn't related to my question. An is a subtype of An-1 and as such An-1 defines some virtual functions overrided by An.

Comment: But then his above code still works. The directly is just the wrong term. An should derive from An-1 (not neccessarily directly).

Comment: It's mixin? If so, maybe it's worth to mention this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define a friend function at global scope which implements the functionality, and have `SpecificPartsOfFunctionality` do nothing more than call it.  E.g.

```
void FunctionalityN(Base* b)
{
    b->DoThings();
    ...
}

class An : public Base
{
    friend void FunctionalityN();
    virtual void SpecificPartOfFunctionality() { FunctionalityN(this); }
    ....
};
```

Strictly speaking FunctionalityN wouldn't even have to be a friend, though it would make things easier.  This makes extending to Fn, Gn, etc. straightforward and subsequently replacing `FunctionalityN` with `NewFunctionalityN` pretty easy, too.

Comment: +1 @Matt. This is improved variation of solution 1, while it have one implementation for SpecificPartOfFunctionality() within An..En.

Comment: @dimba Right.  This doesn't completely eliminate code duplication, though it does minimize it, and so it might be an acceptable compromise since there is an inherent tension between generality (one method for all) and scalability (may be subsequently overridden), and the fact you can't change Base (I assume).  I note that if you can declare `SpecificPartOfFunctionality` pure virtual in `Base` or elsewhere, then you avoid the problem of future developers forgetting to override it.

Comment: No, that wouldn't avoid the problem of future developers forgetting to override it. Because 1) later versions, e.g. A9 where you first override SpecificPart in A3, must consider whether they need to override it, with no compile error if they don't, but 2) if it's pure virtual, then A1 and A2, which don't need SpecificPart, can't be instantiated!

Comment: @Fred Re 1), I was thinking really of Fn, Gn, etc., indeed that's not going to help for An+1.  Re 2), OP is able to modify A1, B1, etc. so he could define it in those classes too (vacuously).  So you're certainly right that there's no gain w.r.t. the A1, 2, 3, hierarchy in making it virtual, rather a cost in added code.  But if it's very important to make sure it gets defined in future F, G, etc. hierarchies, it might be worth it, for that.